# Ubuntu Restricted Extras installation via USC stuck on "Applying Changes"

Tags: software-center, 13.04, ubuntu-restricted-extras

**Ubuntu Restricted Extras installation via USC stuck on "Applying Changes"**

On my HP Envy Touchsmart 14" (Series 14-3010NR), I have recently installed the final release of 13.04 but when I try to install Ubuntu Restricted Extras, the above issue occurs.

On 12.10, I also had the issue but after shutting off my computer to stop teh process *then uninstalling URE then reinstalling it then getting stuck again then uninstalling it then reinstalling it again for a few times then reinstalling Ubuntu then installing URE then getting stuck again then uninstalling it then reinstalling it again for a few times before it finally installed fully.*

Huh?  Simply put, I uninstalled, reinstalled, got stuck, reboot, repeat all multiple times, then reinstall Ubuntu then start the whole process again until it worked on 12.10.

Well, that's quite a problem on its own but this time on 13.04, this "method" won't yield any results and the problem persists.  Maybe I will have to do it even more times than I already have?  I'm not willing to do that again because it's very time consuming.

Update 1: I'm getting stuck at "ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/comic32.exe" when installing URE via terminal but this is probably also the case when instlaling from USC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in previous releases the installation of [ubuntu-restricted-extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras) [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras] requires to accept the Microsoft EULA for MS TTF core fonts.

Unfortunately the window asking for acceptance is hidden behind the USC window but you can present it by clicking on the grey question mark icon on the launcher:

[image]

We can  proceed with installing all other restricted software without accepting the MS licence if we do not need those fonts.

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work.

Comment: @user26358: try to install URE in a terminal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` and [edit] your question with errors you get.

Comment: I'm getting stuck at "ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/comic32.exe"  This was also the case back in 12.10 but uninstalling and reinstalling URE worked after manyh tries somehow.

Comment: You can always refuse to tick that EULA agreement and proceed without installing the fonts.

Comment: same here,

thick the EULA, and click forward but still stuck on applying chnages.